# Shadows for Icon Labels on the Desktop is Appear after Use Split Screen. How to Fix That?

Tags: windows-10, icons, desktop-icons, appearance

I disabled Shadows for Icon Labels on the Desktop in `Advanced system settings -> Advanced -> Performance Settings`:

[image: SETTINGS]

[image: WITHOUT_SHADOWS]

and on start system I don't have shadows (alright). But after I use split sceen or change virtual desktop this shadows is appear (and I can not fix that with enable and disable check mark in `Performance Settings`).

[image: WITH_SHADOWS]

I can fix that only with `sign out` from system and `sign in` again, or restart my PC.

How to Fix That?

I use Windows 10 Version: 1703 Build: 15063.540

Comment: Does restarting (without sign out/sign in) the explorer solve that for temporarily?

Comment: @Biswa restarting solve that problem until I will not use split screen again. I also found this topic: https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/71872-desktop-icon-label-drop-shadows-always-after-split-windows.html with a video demonstration of what happens. But this does not solve my problem. I don't want to restart my system every time when I use split screen.

Comment: Did you see the registry tweak in this [article](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/drop-shadows-for-icon-labels)?

Comment: @Biswa yes. This trick with regedit for users for whom the method with `Performance Settings` does not work. And in this case we still need to restart PC.

Comment: @Biswa do you have Windows 10 installed? This problem not present in your system?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that unchecking the "drop shadows" option would only work for darker desktop backgrounds. If there's part of your background picture that has lighter color, the desktop items on top of that part would still have drop shadows. If you don't mind changing background picture, I find setting desktop background to pure black fillings to be helpful to just mask the shadows. Hope this helps!